# How to get user list from active directory in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get user names from active directory. I used below code and it gives me usernames for some people but it is not all.There are missing names. What do i wrong? I am new on Mvc and ldap. Anyone can help me?

```
   public ActionResult GetUserList()
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.com", "username", "password");

        DirectorySearcher searcher;
        SearchResultCollection results;

        searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname=*))";
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        List<string> list= new List<string>();

        using (searcher)
        {
            results = searcher.FindAll();


            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                string searchOK = result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
                list.Add(searchOK);
            }
        }
        return View(list);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayname=*))";
```

to

```
searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";
```

Not every user must have a display name.
Please also read the samAccountName property